# Glassfish whont start on linux server

Tags: java, linux, glassfish

First i am a total novice at linux so dont hate. I have done the same thing on windows may times and always gotten it to work. Trying on a linux box for the first time.

1)I have installed Glassfish 4 which needs JDK7 or higher.

2)I installed JDK 8

3)I set JAVA_HOME to the JDK

4)I unziped Glassfish.

When i run the following

```
glassfish4/bin/asadmin
```

I get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:620)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:268)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
```

What to do.

I have seen this before and solution has been to set the JDK path. But i cant find anywhere where i am to set the path. **`asenv.conf`** ?

Comment: Are you perhaps running into 32-bit vs 64-bit issues?

Comment: yes that might be... checking

Comment: @EvanKnowles you were right on sorts. Not only did i have the wrong 32/64 bit one i also had the wrong OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Super thanksto @EvanKnowles.

Solution:

1) Downloaded Solaris Sparc version of JDK 7

Thats it folks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your default system java is in old version. You can check it by running:

```
$ java -version
```

To set specific Java for Glassfish open glassfish/config/asenv.conf file and add at the end folowing:

```
AS_JAVA=pathToYourJavaHomeFolder
```